# how to change the length of a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

i have two dictionaries but not the same length. i want to make the length of the bigger dictionary the same as the small one.
i use this but it gives me error, i think, because i can't do it to a dictionary like that.
it gives me this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

```
if len(ints2answers) > len(ints2questions):
    ints2answers = ints2answers[:len(ints2questions)]
elif len(ints2questions) > len(ints2answers):
    ints2questions = ints2questions[:len(ints2answers)]
```

Comment: You can make the second dictionary smaller by deleting some items. But do you know which items to delete?

Comment: yes. i want to delete the items from the last index of the smaller dictionary until the end, since they're sorted.

Comment: They're sorted? Does that mean they're [`OrderedDict`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)?

Comment: Python dictionaries _in general_ are not sorted. Is there some other criterion that you want to use? Like remove the items which are not in the first dictionary?

Comment: no they're normal dictionaries, but since the questions are sorted to their answers, the extra values are not needed.

Comment: Once again, dictionaries are _not_ sorted. Please add examples of your dictionaries.

Comment: yes, i meant that every question in the questions dictionary has an answers in the same index in the answers dictionary.

Comment: That sounds bad. Again, please show us your dictionaries.

Comment: `:n` is a a `slice` object. It can be used with lists, but not dictionaries.  It has no meaning in the dictionary case.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out the dictionary data structure doesn't provide slicing. But you can slice the `items` in the dictionary and convert it back to a dictionary.

```
>>> d = {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
>>> max_len = 2
>>> dict(list(d.items())[:max_len])
{0: 0, 1: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a *Type Error* that means you are doing an unsupported operation for dictionaries.

Dictionaries are unordered lists. That means they have no order. You cannot say which is the first object of the dictionary, instead this is a set of `keys` and `values`.But slicing (`ints2answers[:len(ints2questions)]`) can only be done with a ordered list (i.e. `lists`, `tuples`, `strings`).

If you want to do the above operation with your data, you have to make it a 2D list. This can be done very easily with following code (or you can find your own way)

`myList = [ [k,v] for k, v in myDict.items() ]`

Now you can slice your list and do above operation. If you need to make it a dictionary again, `dict(myList)` will do the job.